# What could lead to the appearance of a wormhole relatively close to our planet?

Tags: space, universe, wormholes

I was thinking of different ways a **wormhole** could appear relatively close to our planet but even reading much about wormholes I can't think of any possible conditions.

I need some theoretical or even better a more relatively scientific explanation (for a sci-fi), or conditions at which a wormhole could appear relatively close to our planet.

If anyone knows of a different body than a wormhole for space and time travel then please include that.

I need to somehow have a body like a wormhole appear in the solar system within reach. But this body should be able to do bad things to our planet and maybe the solar system itself. This body should allow time and space travel and have an entrance and an exit (which doesn't work vice versa).

Comment: There is no **science** to suggest wormholes even can exist. There are speculation, yes. But there is no science for it. So your question is unanswerable. So this gives you great freedom as an author: you can just make something up. Also note that sometimes things should not be over-explained. It does not add to the story, it detracts from it.

Comment: @MichaelK I wouldn't want my way of seeing it as an author to be much contrary to possible explanations and present day science. This really would make a fantasy rather than a sci-fi.

Comment: Wormholes **are** fantasy. You cannot say "I want this fantasy element in my story, but I want it to be based on science". Sorry, you can get one or the other, not both.

Comment: The interstellar economy of the very successful  *[Honorverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorverse)* is based on wormholes. The wormholes just _are_, the author makes to no attempt to explain them; and when the plot requires it, a new one (actually, a new terminal of a known one) is discovered using some unexplained math, and most of the discussion focuses on the economic and political implications of the discovery. Most people understand those. Why would you bother explaining the physics? How many people have the prerequisite knowledge to begin to understand the explanation?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I mean enough to be seen but not enough to be felt.

Comment: "Because the story needs it to appear" "Science experiment gone wrong" "Alien interference" "open mystery". You have to handwave this one which makes this a brain storm question - most people do not like them on this SE

Comment: Einstein and Nathan invented a mathematical method to get rid of singularity in their general relativity equation as they doubt it's existence then, later on to celebrate the occasion sci fi fans decided to bestow it an official name which is still in use til today.

Comment: @user6760 It was Einstein and **Rosen**. The name "wormhole" was coined by John Archibald Wheeler, an American theoretical physicist of considerable note. Science-fiction fans didn't name it at all.

Comment: @MichaelK Wormholes are grounded in a considerable body of science. Their existence is theoretical, which also suggests reasons why their continued existence is unlikely. However, the conditions that need to be met for their stability and remaining is well understood. To call them "fantasy" is ingenuous.

Comment: @a4android: that's his... oh nvm!

Comment: @user6760 Sorry, sport, I tend to be the enemy of misinformation. One of my biggest failings. You were inactive here for a while, good to see you're back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer about how a wormhole can appear in the solar system is quite simple. It was sent here by an advanced alien civilization as part of their setting up a galaxy-spanning faster-than-light transportation network.

The concept has been proposed by the physicist John Cramer building on the ideas of others, but weaving them together in a creative manner.

> However, Matt Visser has metric-engineered a different solution to
>   Einstein’s equations of general relativity from that to Morris,
>   Thorne, and Yurtsever, in which the wormhole is stabilized by another
>   artifact of general relativity, a negative-tension cosmic string36. 
>   Such an object would be self contained, have no dangerous space
>   curvature except near the cosmic string surfaces, and could, in
>   principle, be very large or very small, even down to the Planck-length
>   scale.  A Visser wormhole might also occur naturally in the aftermath
>   of the Big Bang, since both of its components are GR solutions.  We
>   can also hypothesize that if there were passive stability problems
>   with a Visser wormhole, it might be dynamically stabilized externally
>   by an active negative feedback system acting directly on and through
>   one of the wormhole mouths.
>
> Let us assume that we have the capability of producing such Visser
>   wormholes and controlling their size.  If we keep a wormhole mouth
>   microscopic in mass and size, it behaves much like a fundamental
>   particle with a very large mass, perhaps somewhat in excess of the
>   Planck mass of  21.8 micrograms.  For the purposes of calculation, let
>   us assume that we can produce a stabilized microscopic wormhole with a
>   mass of, say, ten Planck masses or 218 micrograms.
>
> Now, we take the two wormhole mouths of this object and thread lines
>   of electrical force through them, until we have passed about 20
>   coulombs of charge through the  wormhole.  This can be done, in
>   principle, with a 20 microampere electron beam passing through the
>   wormhole for about 12 days.  The result is that the wormhole mouth
>   will now have the same charge-to-mass ratio as a proton and will
>   behave like a proton in the electric and magnetic fields of a particle
>   accelerator.  (We note that such an object would have to have some
>   minimum radius, because if the electric field at the throat was too
>   strong, it would pull positrons out of the vacuum and reduce the
>   charge by field emission.)
>
> Now we transport what we will henceforth call the “traveling wormhole
>   mouth” to Meyrin, Switzerland near Geneva and put it into CERN’s new
>   Large Hadronic Collider (LHC) there.  The other wormhole mouth remains
>   in our laboratory, along with various stabilizing and steering
>   equipment (described later).  We assume that by the time that we are
>   able to do this, the LHC will have achieved its full design capacity
>   and will be able to accelerate each of its colliding proton beams to 7
>   TeV (7 x 1012 electron volts).  We use the LHC to accelerate the
>   wormhole mouth to the same energy per unit rest mass as a 7 TeV
>   proton, extract the beam that contains it, point it at a star of
>   interest, and send it on its way.  (Presumably, we would do this in an
>   operation with a number of wormhole-mouths pointed at a selection of
>   candidate stars that might have earth-like planets in orbit around
>   them.)
>
> A proton with a total energy of 7.0 TeV will have a Lorentz gamma
>   factor (g = [1-(v/c)2]-½  = E/M) of 7,455.  The accelerated wormhole
>   mouth will have the same Lorentz factor.  This is the factor by which
>   the total mass-energy E of the proton moving at this high velocity v
>   exceeds its rest mass M.  It is also the factor by which time dilates,
>   i.e., by which the clock of a hypothetical observer riding on the
>   proton would slow down.  The wormhole is traveling at a velocity that
>   is only a tiny fraction less than the speed of light, so it travels a
>   distance of one light-year in one year.  However, to an observer
>   riding on the wormhole mouth, because of relativistic time dilation
>   the distance of one light year is covered in only 1/7,455 of a year or
>   70.5 minutes.
>
> Moreover, back on Earth if we peek through the wormhole mouth at rest
>   in our laboratory, we see the universe from the perspective of an
>   observer riding on the traveling wormhole mouth.  In other words, in
>   70.5 minutes after its launch from CERN, through the wormhole we will view the universe one light year away.  Later, in 11.7 hours we will
>   view the surroundings 10 light-years away.  In 4.9 days, we will view
>   the surroundings 100 light years away.  And so on.
>
> This is a remarkable result.  How is it possible that, if the
>   traveling wormhole mouth requires 100 years, as viewed from Earth, to
>   travel 100 light years, we can view its destination as observers
>   looking through the wormhole in a bit less than 5 days?  It is
>   because, as pointed out by Morris, Thorne and Yurtserver7, the special
>   relativity of time dilation makes a wormhole with one high-velocity
>   mouth into a time machine.  The wormhole mouth, which from our
>   perspective has taken 100 years to reach a point 100 light years away,
>   connects back in time to its departure point only 5 days after it
>   left.  In effect, it has moved 100 light years at a speed of 7,455 c.
>
> But could the traveling wormhole mouth be aimed so accurately from its
>   start at CERN that it might it actually pass through another star
>   system many light years away, to survey its planets, etc.?  And could
>   it stop when it got there?   The fortunate answer is yes.
>
> Momentum back reaction can be used to steer the traveling wormhole
>   mouth.   The direction of travel, as viewed through the wormhole, can
>   be monitored.  Course corrections can be made by directing a
>   high-intensity light beam through the laboratory based wormhole mouth
>   at right angles to the direction of travel.  The beam will emerge from
>   the traveling wormhole mouth “sideways” giving it momentum sideways
>   momentum in the other direction.  The exit mouth will lose a bit of
>   mass-energy in this process, but it will also be gaining some mass
>   energy as interstellar gas passes through it and emerges from the
>   laboratory wormhole mouth.  We note that, in terms of momentum change
>   vs. mass gain of the wormhole mouth, the use of light is preferable to
>   high energy particles, even though the momentum carried by light is
>   only its energy divided by the speed of light, because it keeps the
>   wormhole mass gain/loss small per unit momentum change.
>
> Assuming precision steering can be accomplished by applying such
>   momentum changes, stopping is not too difficult.  The exit mouth will
>   still have the large electric charge used for acceleration in the LHC
>   and consequently will lose energy rapidly by ionizing interactions as
>   it passes through any gas.  It can be steered to make passes through
>   the upper atmospheres of planets or to have grazing collisions with
>   atmosphere of the star itself, until its great initial velocity has
>   been dissipated.  In this process, considerable mass will pass through
>   the traveling mouth, and it will gain this mass-energy by back
>   reaction.  This can be compensated by sending low-velocity mass
>   through in the other direction.  The large charge can be reduced at
>   the same time by sending charged particles through.
>
> The decelerated wormhole mouth can tour the star system, propelled by
>   high momentum beams sent through the stay-at-home mouth in the
>   laboratory.  Such steering will tend to reduce the wormhole mass,
>   partially compensating for the mass-gain it received in decelerating
>   and perhaps in sampling planetary atmospheres.
>
> Now that the wormhole mouth has arrived at the star system of
>   interest, a survey of the planets can begin.  We assume that we have
>   laboratory control of the diameter of the wormhole mouth, and that it
>   can be enlarged to a diameter that is convenient for sampling.  If a
>   habitable planet is found, the wormhole mouth can be brought to its
>   surface, and samples can be extracted through the wormhole and
>   analyzed, (perhaps sending compensating mass back in the other
>   direction to keep the wormhole mouth masses in balance).
>
> Ultimately, when the survey is complete, the wormhole can be expanded,
>   permitting robot precursors, planetary explorers, colonists, and
>   freight to move through.  Again, the mass of the wormhole mouths would
>   have to be managed, moving equal masses in the two directions during
>   wormhole transits, perhaps by sending compensating masses of water
>   through pipes.  This scheme could allow very rapid travel to and
>   colonization of various star systems containing earth-like planets. 
>   Thus, if stable wormholes are possible at all, they may represent a
>   path to the stars that would sweep away many of our previous concepts
>   and prejudices about how the stars can and should be reached.

Source: [Exotic Paths To The Stars](http://www.gregorybenford.com/uncategorized/exotic-paths-to-the-stars-john-cramer/)

While Cramer suggested this wormhole transportation network might be built by space-faring humans, there is no reason why advanced aliens couldn't get there first.

In summary, the wormhole arrives in the solar system because it was dispatched here to form part of a faster-than-light galactic wormhole transport network.

Comment: This concept is used by physicist Luke Campbell for his VergeWorlds setting: http://panoptesv.com/RPGs/Settings/VergeWorlds/TheVerge.php with interesting side-effects, like causality attacks (breaking wormhole connections by forcing them to loop through time, which cause the weakest link of the loop to break). If you want to use this model, I recommend checking what he has done with it here.

Comment: @Eth Neh, I wouldn't want to copy someone elses ideas. But this is an interesting theory.